# cakephp change language on fly

Tags: cakephp, multilingual, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

My site is in 2 languages (english and italian)

**My SiteMessagesController.php controller code:**

```
public function index() {
    $this->SiteMessage->locale = 'it';
    $this->SiteMessage->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('siteMessages', $this->paginate());
}
```

Above code shows all messages in italian [language from database](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html). If I `comment` the 1st line of code, then it will show messages in english.

If I go with this in whole site, I have to write `$this->SiteMessage->locale = 'it';` line before `$this->ModelName->find();` in each action of each controller.

Is there any way to set `$locale` to `'it'` for each model?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  I would have guessed @dr Hannibal Lecter's answer was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, this will do:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'ita');
```

If you put this somewhere like your `AppController::beforeFilter()` it should work for the entire app, not individual models or queries. See book on [I18n and L10n](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) for more info.

Comment: @lakumg: Are you sure you're not overriding something somewhere? The page I linked explicitly claims that this line is all it takes for that to work.

Comment: I am using translate behavior (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html). So your answer will not work with it.

Comment: @lakumg: I know you're using the translate behaviour, ergo this: "**Doing this will ensure that both I18n and TranslateBehavior access the same language value.**", from the page I linked. This is exactly what's supposed to work unless you're doing something very special and overriding something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

put locale in AppModel.

eg: This one is for english
  `public $locale = 'en_us';`